# I search for a solid material which dissolves in water very slowly, around 1 micrometre per hour measured from the water-contact-surface

Tags: materials, material-science, chemistry

I know there are some watersolutable Polymers out there like Polyvinylalcohol, but that would dissolve to fast. Is there some material that dissolves at around 1 micrometre per hour, regardless of pH Value, Temperature or flowspeed of the nearby water? I thought about a combination of some materials, maybe something like a watersolutable mineral with some other material in a mixture? Or something that corrodes at that speed?

Just looking for suggestions, thank you!

Comment: Tolerances? The world is full of feedback- by dissolving, you alter the water.  Regardless of pH, flow rate, etc might as well be regardless of if it is in water.

Comment: Tolerance: around 0.3 microns per hour. There would be no feedback because the water would be transported away, so there would always be "fresh" water as dissolvent.

Comment: You said regardless of flow rate ("flow speed"?) so that means down to whatever infinitesimal quantity you can still consider "transported away" turning what would be simple in a very specific steady state scenario into one night impossible to achieve.

Comment: you have a point, what i meant was that the dissolve rate should be pretty much constant at different flow rates, at small pH-Value changes or temperature changes. The flow  rate is high enough that I would say there is no feedback from already dissolved material, so it is not diffusion but a constant stream of water that is in contact with the material (turbulent flow).

Comment: If you describe purpose of this, we possibly could advice better solution. This looks like XY problem. Every chemical reaction rate depends on temperature, reagent concentration and stirring velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps limestone dust would work as limestone dissolves slowly in water . I was considering saying salt but that would probably dissolve too quickly .
Bit of an odd one but maybe experiment with diffeyground up tablets .
I'm sure some tablets will dissolve at the rate you require . Chalk dust. Flour
Even sugar dissolves slowly in cold water. Even hot water .
I know if I fail to stir my coffee sufficiently. That I end up with most of the sugar left at the bottom of the cup .giving me a sweet suprise in my last swig lol. Not sweet as in pleasant. Blurgh lol.

I guess experimentation is the only way to resolve this matter .
As disolve rates will vary dramatically.

Funnily I was just considering this very point only minutes before finding this forum.

I was considering a way of making epoxy resin porus by mixing the epoxy 50/50 with something that would dissolve away . Also something I could cost routes of a plant with before setting in epoxy and then dissolving the coating away leaving little chambers the routes could live in filled with nutrients so I'd have a see through plant pot I'm effect. Tho again it would need to be somewhat pourus so I could get the nutrients into the chambers .

I don't know. Just one of those things you sit thinking about when you have time on your hands .lol.

Anyway good luck with your challenge. And if you find a solution or indeed if I do.

Let's not keep it to ourselves and post our discoveries here .

Comment: Use metal. Apply the needed voltage or current to get the ionization rate you want. By managing current, you can make it largely independent of the environmental conditions. A pulse generator would work well and is very well understood in corrosion prevention; you just want to reverse the process like for the source in a plating operation.